# How to expand the command line to the whole screen in MC?

Tags: midnight-commander

Is it possible to expand the command line to the whole screen (to show several lines on the terminal) in Midnight Commander without exiting it? I mean I want to switch from two tabs to a raw terminal to see what was the output of the last command (it could be several screens long). How can it be done?

P.S. I did read the entire help but wasn't able to find how to do it.

Comment: Voting to close, too helpful to not be flagged as a silly duplicate!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can hide the Midnight Commander Window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> again to return back to Midnight Commander.